# if(isset($_POST['action'])) not working

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to echo out a javascript to see if(isset($_POST['action')) returns true. But everytime I click the button. It does nothing contrary to what it should be doing. What seems to be the cause?

EDIT: I included the entire code. Is something wrong here? I tried almost every suggestion but still not working.

```
<div class="container">
<form action="" method="post">  

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col">
<h5>Patient Details</h5>
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">assignment_ind</i>
    <input type="text" name="patientName" class="validate">
    <label for="patientName">Patient Name</label>
</div>

  <div class="input-field col s3">
    <select name="bloodType" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Blood Group</option>
      <?php
         $q = $db->query("select * from tblbloodtype where btStatus = '1' ORDER by bloodTypeName"); 
        while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo"<option value=".$r['bloodTypeID'].">".$r['bloodTypeName']."</option>";
         }
        ?>
    </select>
    <label>Blood Group</label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field col s3">
    <select name="city" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select City</option>
      <?php
         $q = $db->query("select * from tblcity where status = '1' ORDER by cityName"); 
        while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo"<option value=".$r['cityID'].">".$r['cityName']."</option>";
         }
        ?>
    </select> 
    <label>City where it is needed</label>
  </div>
</div><!--ROW-->

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12 ">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">business</i>
          <textarea id="hospitalName" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
          <label for="hospitalName">Hospital Name and Address</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
    <input type="text" name="doctorName" class="validate">
    <label for="doctorName">Doctor's Name</label>
</div>
</div>
<h5>Contact Details</h5>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
    <input type="text" name="contactName" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9']+" class="validate">
    <label for="contactName">Contact Name</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col">
    <input type="email" name="email"  pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" class="validate">
    <label for="email">Contact Email</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col">
    <input type="text" name="contactNum" pattern="[0-9+]{7,13}" class="validate">
    <label for="contactNum">Contact Number</label>
</div>
    <input class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" value="Send Request" name="action">
    </form>
    </div><!--CONTAINER-->

<?php


if(isset($_POST['action'])){
    echo "<script>alert('Success! Redirecting to homepage..');</script>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem, first of all thank you for your efforts.

As you can see on my code above, I put a `required` attribute on my input tag. Therefore, unless I choose something that has a value in it I can successfully echo the alert.

It took me so long before noticing that because it does not show an error message that I am required to choose something.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$_REQUEST['action ']
```

To

```
$_REQUEST['action']
```

(Note the removed space at the end)

Also change

```
   <script>alert('Success! Redirecting to homepage..);</script>
```

To

```
  <script>alert('Success! Redirecting to homepage..');</script>
```

(Note the quote after the two dots)

Meta tags are allowed only in the header section. Try removing this line:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
```

You can use meta in the body section like this for semantic purposes:

```
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
```

And, as noted here http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_missing

> This technique should be used **sparingly**. Only use meta with content
>   for information that cannot otherwise be marked up.

So you have to avoid that.

EDIT:

The first 3 divs do not have closing tags. Close these divs. Not closing them, `<script>` tag is printed by php inside the  tag.

Also replace this:

```
echo"<option value=".$r['bloodTypeID'].">".$r['bloodTypeName']."</option>";
```

with this:

```
echo "<option value='".$r['bloodTypeID']."'>".$r['bloodTypeName']."</option>";
```

(Note the single quotes in the value attribute)

Same thing for

```
  echo"<option value=".$r['cityID'].">".$r['cityName']."</option>";
```

Replace it with:

```
echo "<option value='".$r['cityID']."'>".$r['cityName']."</option>";
```

(Note the spaces between echo)

Comment: Still doesn't echo the alert.

Comment: Did you also add the quote to the alert function?

Comment: Try also instead of this <script> to have this: <script type='text/javascript'>

Comment: Yes. I did. Is there something wrong with this? 
`<input class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" value="Send Request" name="action">` I'm guessing there something wrong not with my php but in my html code.

Comment: It seems good to me. What do these lines contain? 
...Some codes here..

Comment: Try instead of > in the input closing tag to have />

Comment: Meta tags are allowed only in the header section

Comment: Try removing this line echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";

Comment: I edited my post.I included the entire code instead of "Some code"

Comment: Its seems that you are missing some closing tags in the divs you have. Like the first <div class="row"> I dont see where it is closed.

Comment: Also this </div><!--CONTAINER--> is not closing the container div

Comment: Thanks for noticing. FIxed it now. But the isset stuff is still dead af lol

Comment: Try moving the if isset block above the container div. Did it work?

Comment: See my edit, is it working now?

Comment: Still not working :C

Comment: Is this your full, full code? As @Aravindh Gopi mentioned, where is $db initialized? Also where is the html, header and body tags? And your css imports?

Comment: The problem seems to be on the selection of Blood Group. I tried to comment them out one by one starting from the bottom upto the top by enclose each `<div></div>` in <!---->. It's started echoing the alert until I reach at the selection of the blood group.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
    echo "<script>alert('Success! Redirecting to homepage..');</script>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
}
```

Removed space in `$_POST['action']`

single quote closed `'Success! Redirecting to homepage..'`

space given after echo `echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";`

Answer (score -2):

Remove Space in `$_POST['action  ']` to `$_POST['action']`.